# LoadTypeLibEx is failing while running an application in session 0 (service session)

Tags: visual-c++, sessionid

In my Application, I am loading a type library as follows

```
ITypeLib *typelib = NULL;

tlbpath = "some path"

hr = LoadTypeLibEx(tlbpath ,REGKIND_REGISTER,&typelib);

hr = RegisterTypeLibForUser(typelib,tlbpath,NULL);
```

When i run as administrator/user, I am able to load tlb and all entries are loaded into registry.

When i run same application through service in session 0, I am getting error as `TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY` while loading typelib.

Also, does `UnRegisterTypeLibForUser` will remove all entries that are created with `LoadTypeLibEx`.

In my case `UnRegisterTypeLibForUser` is executing fine but entries are not getting removing in registry.

I used below code:

```
UnRegisterTypeLibForUser(tlibatr->guid,tlibatr->wMajorVerNum,tlibatr->wMinorVerNum, LOCALE_NEUTRAL, SYS_WIN32);
```

Can anyone tell the reason why `LoadTypeLibEx` was failed to register when running application in session 0 and how to fix it?

Comment: Do not obfuscate the path you are using, it matters a great deal.

Comment: Hans Passant- Did you mean tlbpath,I gave correct path and it is working fine in session 2.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for my problem.

I gave virtual drive path of tlb and not system path.
ie X:....\vlt.tlb   and not  E:..\XRoot...\vlt.tlb

So in session 0 , we need to give system path.

Thanks  Hans Passant.

Can anyone tell why UnRegisterTypelibForUser is not removing entries in registry?